# Find x, and prove by induction that Q(n) holds for all n ≥ x.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

**Question:**

Let $Q(n)$  be a statement $"n! < " n^n"$ and let $x$ be the smallest natural number
for which $Q(n)$ would be true.  Find $x$, and prove using induction that $Q(n)$ would hold for all $n≥ x.$

[Note: Take $0^0 = 1$]

**Here is what I have so far,**

Let $Q(n)$ be $"n! < " n^n"$ where $n$ is an integer greater than 1.

Replacing $n$ by 2 in the expression for $Q(n)$,
$$Q(2): 2! < 2^2$$

**Basis Step:** $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 2! = 2 < 4 = 2^2$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad  Q(2)$ holds true

**Induction Hypothesis:** $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad$ Let $Q(k)$ be true,

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad  k! < k^k$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $ Need to prove that $Q(k+1)$ is true ,

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (k+1)! < (k+1)^{k+1}$

**Induction Step:** $\quad \quad  \qquad \qquad $ Need to prove that Q(k+1) is also true,
$$(k+1)! = (k+1) \cdot k!\\
< (k+1) \cdot k^k \quad \leftarrow 1\\ 
< (k+1) \cdot (k+1)^k \quad \leftarrow 2 \quad (\mbox{Since } k < k+1 )\\
= (k + 1)^{k+1}$$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad  Q(k+1)$ holds true

**Conclusion:** $\qquad \qquad$ By Induction, $Q(n)$ is true for all positive integer $n$ greater than 1.

Would there be a need, in between the steps labelled by arrows 1 and 2 to expand:
$$(k+1)^k = k^k$$
$$(k+1)^k = k$$

I have been trying to work this problem out and I have been wondering whether this would be the right way to go about solving it.If not, could someone work it out to show me how?

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see, what you have is perfectly fine! nicely done!

Comment: Your proof is good. In the step labelled by arrow 1 you are just appealing to the inductive hypothesis and that is fine. In the step labelled by arrow 2 you are using the fact that $k^k < (k + 1)^k$ and it might be good to justify that: e.g., by the binomial theorem $(k + 1)^k = k^k + C_1^k k^ {k -1} + \ldots < k^k$.